# Windows Azure automation script error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, ui-automation

I am trying an automation script to create a website, security account, databases. But when I am trying to run the script I am getting the following error:

```
New-AzureStorageAccount : BadRequest: The location constraint is not valid
OperationID : 'e697345f05dd22b787642c1e515354e0'
At C:\MyFixIt\Automation\New-AzureStorage.ps1:93 char:16
+ ... orageAcct = New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $Name -Locati ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureStorageAccount], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.StorageServices.NewAzureStorageAccount
   Command

VERBOSE: 8:36:46 PM - Completed Operation: New-AzureStorageAccount
Failed to create a Windows Azure storage account. Failure in New-AzureStorage.ps1
At C:\MyFixIt\Automation\New-AzureStorage.ps1:100 char:5
+     throw "Failed to create a Windows Azure storage account. Failure  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Failed to creat...zureStorage.ps1:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Failed to create a Windows Azure storage account. Failure in New-AzureStorage.ps1
```

Comment: Please share the parameters you provided to `New-AzureStorageAccount` Cmdlet. From the error it looks like you are providing an incorrect value for `location` parameter.

Comment: Hello, It is a script where the location, this is the parameter in script

Comment: .PARAMETER  Location
    Specifies a Windows Azure location. The location must support web 
    sites. The default value is "West US,East US,North Central US". 

    Valid values:
    -- East Asia
    -- East US
    -- North Central US
    -- North Europe
    -- West Europe
    -- West US

Answer (score 0):

Is your issue resolved? From the error it appears to be an invalid location specified

Hopefully you have something like:

```
New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName "testaccount" -Label "TestAccount" -Location "North Central US"
```

For a list of valid locations, please check https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services